# How to transfer the original color from the blender to Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, 3d, qml, blender

I convert a blender image(*.obj) into a mesh with the Balsam tool and inserted it into the QML. But it does not import color and texture. How can I import these materials into the Qt?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find another file **.mtl** along with **.obj** file.

The .mtl file is a material library file which contains defined colors, textures etc..

Mostly there should be same name for both the files.

Ensure the material file is placed along with object file.

Comment: Thank you, yes, file .mtl is with .obj file, but I do not know how to convert this file to mesh and add it in Qt.